# Confusion about notation of stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation, regression

I do not have a mathematical background and I often find myself struggling with notations in certain scientific papers etc.

a) Am I right that the observations of a stochastic process can be written as:

$\{x_t\}^n_{t=1}$  ?

b) Can the same notation be applied to a series of variables in general? For example: Could the residuals of a simple linear regression model estimated via OLS be notated as

$\{e_t\}^n_{t=1}$ ?

I am really struggling with all the different notations and I am simply trying to define a personal sort of standard on how to notate different things.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: NO; $\{ x_t \}$ needs that the "index" is $t$ and not $i$. See [Stochastic process: Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process#Notation): $\{ X(t) \}_{t \in T}$.

Comment: Oh sorry that was just a typo. I edited it.

Comment: Ok; but please note that this means that the number of "observations" is finite: $x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_n$.

Comment: Also, the notation I am referring to here is used in quite a lot of scientific papers I was reading recently. And I am confused wether it is right or the one you are referring to is right, or are they both right?

Comment: Yes I understand that.

Comment: When you write $\{ X(t) \}_{t \in T}$ the "index set" $T$ can be whatever: for example, a set of *real* numbers, in which case the set of "observations" can be infinite.

Comment: Alright, thank you! Also, referring to b): I am not sure wether the residuals of an estimated regression formula are a stochastic process, because reapplying OLS to the regression formula with the same data would result in the exact same residuals. Can I still use the notation I am referring to?